# FLVPlayback and GET variable - runtime error #1090

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Easy to reproduce:

```
    public function FLVTest() {
        var p:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
        var url:String = "foo.flv";
        p.source = url;
    }
```

This works fine.

But adding some GET variable to the url by doing something like this...

```
var url:String = "foo.flv" + "?bar=123456789";
```

... results in following error message at runtime:

> Exception fault: TypeError: Error #1090: XML parser failure element is malformed

```
at fl.video::SMILManager/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::xmlLoadEventHandler()[D:\DEVELOP\test_lib\fl\video\SMILManager.as:240]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

Two things that I don't like about this error:

1. I can't seem to catch it anywhere for further investigation.
2. I absolutely don't know what it means. Well yes, I know what malformed XML is, but what does this have to do with XML parsing?

Hope someone can help me out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The FLVPlayback component doesn't allow for a query in the source. Depending on what you need to do with that query, you might be able to parse it before setting the source. Otherwise, you may need to create your own video player class that can handle query strings. I did find a link that walks you through modifying the FLVPlayback source:

http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/995/1/Writing-a-Custom-YouTube-Player-for-a-Google-Gadget/Page1.html

I haven't tested this, but looks like it could solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looked quite good indeed. I modified the NCManager class (in fact I implemented a subclass) as suggested in the article. And indeed MyNCManager tries to open a http connection despite the query in the source. But then just nothing happens, no READY-event is fired. I added a STATE_CHANGE listener, the event is fired and the event.state is VideoState.CONNECTION_ERROR...

Comment: This sucks.  I have the same problem.  Guess we can't use the old querystring + random query trick to ensure browser isn't caching a file.